# Managing a linked list with pthreads

Tags: c, multithreading, linked-list, pthreads, simulation

I am attempting to simulate a bank with a line of customers represented by a linked list with a thread calculating the probability that a customer walks in (with a preset probability) every unit of time and adds the customer to the end of the line while several teller threads remove a customer from the beginning of the line and I keep getting segmentation faults at seemingly unpredictable points during each simulation.  Below is the code I use for adding too and removing from the list.  The error seems to occur  because the customer thread is attempting to add while a teller is removing.

```
void addToQ(int x, void *arg){
    printf("ADD ATTEMPT\n");
    struct shiftInfo *info = (struct shiftInfo *) arg;
    if (head -> ID == -1){ //No clients in line
        head -> ID = x;
        head -> next = dummy;
        tail = head;
    }

    else{ //clients already in line
        tail -> next = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
        tail = tail -> next;
        tail -> ID = x;
        tail -> next = dummy;
        info -> inQ++;
    }
    printf("ADD SUCCESS\n");
}
//Removes node closest to root
//Assumes: root != end
void removeFromQ(void *arg){
    printf("REMOVE ATTEMPT\n");
    struct shiftInfo *info = (struct shiftInfo *) arg;
    if (head -> next == dummy){ //only one element
        printf("SCENARIO 1\n");
        head -> ID = -1;
    }
    else{
        printf("SCENARIO 2\n");
        curr = head -> next;
        head = curr -> next;
        printf("Halfway\n");
        if ((head -> next == NULL) || (head -> next == dummy))
            tail = head;
    }
    info -> inQ--;
    printf("REMOVE SUCCESS\n");
}
```

Here are the thread functions:

```
void *customerT(void *arg){
    int custID = 100;
    float newCust = 0;
    struct shiftInfo *info = (struct shiftInfo *) arg;
    float aRate = info -> arrivalRate;
    pthread_mutex_lock (&start); //Ensures Customers don't start before Tellers get to work
    pthread_mutex_unlock (&start);
    while(0<info -> simTime){
        newCust = (double)rand() / (double)RAND_MAX;
        if (newCust <= aRate){
            pthread_mutex_lock (&start);
            addToQ(custID,(void *)info);
            pthread_mutex_unlock (&start);
            custID++;
            }
        sleep(1/60);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
 }


void *teller(void *arg){
    struct shiftInfo *info = (struct shiftInfo *) arg;
    int clientID;
    int clients = info -> inQ;
    pthread_mutex_lock (&start); //Ensures tellers dont start before customers arrive
    pthread_mutex_unlock (&start);
    while(0<info -> simTime){
        pthread_mutex_lock (&accessQ);
        clients = info -> inQ;
        if(head -> ID > 0){
            pthread_mutex_lock (&start);
            removeFromQ((void *)info);
            pthread_mutex_unlock (&start);
            printf("CLIENT OBTAINED\n");
        }
        printf("In Q %d\n", clients);
        pthread_mutex_unlock (&accessQ);
        sleep((info -> serviceTime)/60);
        }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

and in case it is relevant, here is the manager thread function:

```
//Creates Customer thread, Teller threads, and timer thread
void *mainThread(void *info){
    head = (NODE *)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    head -> ID = -1;
    head -> next = dummy;
    tail = head;
    int status;
    struct shiftInfo *I = info; 
    pthread_mutex_init(&start, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&removeID, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&accessQ, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_lock (&start);

    printf("Scheduling Tellers\n");
    pthread_t threads[(I -> tellers)];
    for (int i = 0; i < (I -> tellers); i++){
        I -> threadID = i;
        status = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, teller, (void *)info);
        if (status){
            printf("ERROR CODE: %d\n", status);
            exit(-1);
        }
    }

    printf("Preparing Customers\n");
    pthread_t customer;
    status = pthread_create(&customer, NULL, customerT, (void *)info);
        if (status){
            printf("ERROR CODE: %d\n", status);
            exit(-1);
        }

    printf("Making Timer\n");
    pthread_t time;
        status = pthread_create(&time, NULL, timer, (void *)info);
        if (status){
            printf("ERROR CODE: %d\n", status);
            exit(-1);
        }

    pthread_mutex_unlock (&start);
}
```

Comment: So, what is your question actually?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to stop the segmentation fault.  I'm using mutex to make access to the line exclusive but it keeps attempting to add while removing and I'd like to know why. Also, I don't see why that would create a segmentation fault since removals access the tail and adds access the head. @eyalm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code right here looks wrong:

```
curr = head -> next;
head = curr -> next;
```

Consider the case where your list looks like:  `head -> node -> dummy`.  After running the above code, `head` will be pointing at `dummy`, which you surely do not want. Try changing the code to this:

```
curr = head;
head = curr -> next;
```

Edit: The reason you get negative customers is that in `addToQ`, you don't increment `info->inQ` when the list starts empty (the top half of your `if` statement).  You need `info->inQ++` always, just like you have `info->inQ--` always in `removeFromQueue`.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed the segmentation fault, however now I am somehow getting a negative amount of customers in the queue. @JS1